# ASP.NET Core Identity Implementation using Cassandra Database

Tags: cassandra, asp.net-core

I am building an ASP.NET Core MVC application using the Cassandra Database on Windows.

I need help implementing ASP.NET Core Identity with Cassandra.

On Google I found `AspNet.Identity.Cassandra` in the version  2.0.0.1, but it's not compatible with ASP.NET Core 1.0.

Comment: What's your question or **concrete** problem? Asking us to find resources (guides, tutorials) or libraries for you is off-topic. Please read the FAQ before asking a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3):

I'm working on data store adapter for [ASP.NET Core Identity](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity)
 which allows you to build ASP.NET Core web applications, including membership, login, and user data. With this library, you can store your user's membership related data on Apache Cassandra.

> Please note the library is in alpha version and needs to be finished

If you want to try it, follow these steps:

1 - Run the following command from the package manager console to install Cassandra identity provider.

```
Install-Package AspNetCore.Identity.Cassandra -Version 1.0.0-alpha1
```

2 - Add settings to **appsettings.json**

```
{   
    "CassandraNodes": [
        "127.0.0.1"
    ], 
    "CassandraOptions": {
        "KeyspaceName": "identity",
        "Replication": {
            "class": "NetworkTopologyStrategy",
            "datacenter1": "1"
        }
    } 
}
```

3 - Configure services in **Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{    
    // CassandraOptions configuration
    services.Configure<CassandraOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("CassandraOptions"));

    // Cassandra ISession initialization
    services.AddCassandraSession<Cassandra.ISession>(() =>
    {
        var cluster = Cassandra.Cluster.Builder()
            .AddContactPoints(Configuration.GetSection("CassandraNodes").GetChildren().Select(x => x.Value))
            .Build();
        var session = cluster.Connect();
        return session;
    });

    // Added custom Cassandra stores
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
        .UseCassandraStores<Cassandra.ISession>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    // Other code omitted
}
```

4 - And finally initialize DB in **Program.cs**

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build()
            .InitializeIdentityDb<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>();
}
```

For more information check [project site](https://github.com/lkubis/AspNetCore.Identity.Cassandra) at github.

Comment: @LW001 I've improved my answer

Answer (score 0):

**Few Option**

1. Try implement your own cassandra identity for ASP.net core, there is many sample how to create your Custom IdentityUser for ASP.net (using Google) then make it work with Cassandra
2. Fork / Update the AspNet.Identity.Cassandra [project](https://github.com/joshuadeanhall/AspNet.Identity.Cassandra) to .net core (open source, so makes easy to implement your own)
3. Use another provider, instead of Cassandra Database
4. Request update on github (link on section 2.)